# How to convert these character fields to time stamp in hive

Tags: date, hadoop, hive

I have these  character fields `actv_date` and `actv_time` in a hive table

```
    ap_actv_date           
          171205 (YYMMDD)  
    ap_actv_time  
         1954359 (HHMMSSF)
```

I want the output to be a time stamp field of format  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.f`

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(ap_actv_date,ap_actv_time), 'YYMMDDHHMMSSF'))
```